# How to use "using static" with generic classes?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, generic-list, using-declaration

C# has an `using static` directive since C# 6.0 which is allows to includes more specific things (like classes, interfaces etc.) than namespaces. Well, I tried to include generic type class (`System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` to be clear). I used `using static System.Collections.Generic.List<T>;` and program failed. Is there a way to include generic type classes by using `using static` directive?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to use `using static` with `List<T>`? Do you know what `using static` is used for? (Hint: Read the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive#static-modifier)

Comment: It is in fact possible to use generics in a `using static`, but only by instantiating them (`using static System.Collections.Generic.List<int>;`). In the specific case of `List` this is almost certainly not meaningful. You may be confusing this application of `using` with how Java deals with imports, but that's not what `using static` is for.

Comment: The closest you can get to making only specific types available is aliasing, with something like `using IntList = System.Collections.Generic.List<int>;` (again, this requires instantiating in the case of generics). This is generally intended only to resolve name clashes when they do occur, not as a way to pick and choose from namespaces, which the C# designers didn't consider useful.